# NSISdl could not open file during download

Tags: nsis

I'm using NSIS to create an installer which will install files from a web server. I'm using the NSISdl plugin to download the files but they are not downloading, it just says Download Failed: failed to open file.

This is the section which is doing the download, could I be missed something here.

```
 Section "Aquiva"
    ; Set    output path to the installation directory.
    SetOutPath $INSTDIR

    ;Include files from this location, and copy that to the current
    ;out path

    NSISdl::download http://41.78.239.158/Aquiva.exe
Pop $R0 ;Get the return value
  StrCmp $R0 "success" +3
    MessageBox MB_OK "Download failed: $R0"
    Quit

SectionEnd ; end the section
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `inetc` for this purpose:

```
inetc::get "http://41.78.239.158/Aquiva.exe" "$EXEDIR\Aquiva.exe"
pop $R0
DetailPrint "Result: $R0"
```

You can get it [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in)

If you insist on using `NSISdl`, your problem is probably due to not specifying the destination file, try this:

```
NSISdl::download http://41.78.239.158/Aquiva.exe "$INSTDIR\Aquiva.exe"
pop $R0
...
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error Download Failed: http/1.0 404 not found but the file is there? It shows 2 progress bars one for downloading and one for connecting. Only the downloading bar shows progress, what could be the problem?

Comment: @VictorMarisa when I paste `http://41.78.239.158/Aquiva.exe` in my browser address bar I get `Error 404: Not Found` so I guess everything is working as expected...